How to check if PDF is CMYK (not a repeat question!)
I know there is basically the same post on this website already however I have two issues that complicate things: I don't have adobe Pro and I also do not have indesign.
I have a PDF brochure that has a colored front and everything else is in black and white. However I just received the msg from the printers that 'parts of the pdf are in RGB and they need the entire file to be CMYK'. I don't even really know what that means, since I was not aware a file could be CMYK and RGB at the same time, after I asked for clarification they told me I need to convert the entire file to CMYK color profile.
Which I think I might have manged to do using a software called Scribus and Google and a different version with PDF24, but I want to check if I actually accomplished this before sending it back to the printers and also so I can check future projects before sending them.
This is for work, I can't get new software, especially not paid software, does anyone know of any way that I could find out the color profile of this pdf file?

PDF is not one thing, its a container of things. So individual things inside the PDF file have their own settings. You probably want to use PDF/X-1a:2003 because it enforces that there is only naked CMYK on everything (or X-3 flavors but thats harder)

There are free online PDF editor - they seem to focus much more on changing text and images than showing the PDF data. Unfortunately, I've never used any. Most in this community will use Acrobat. I did just try a couple free online tools with a simple spot color PDF, I couldn't find any way to check inks or colors, or any way to see that colors were spot at all. I did not register a Canva account to try theirs - it may be better (But I'd think Adobe's free tool would be best). This is a 30 second task with Acrobat. I think you'll just have to search if you don't want to pay for anything

Good question. First some ideas.
A PDF is a container that normally is an output file, meaning that the file itself was created in another software and then exported into a specific "flavor" of PDF.
This is important. A PDF needs a specific flavor. This is the export profile.
Some profiles are stricter than others. For print, the series of profiles called X is for print, for example, PDFX-1, and PDFX-3. These profiles indicate among other things that no raster image or colored object is on RGB.
The one who applies the profile instructions and requirements is the software used to generate the PDF.
But some other profiles just use whatever it is on the original file. Some PDF documents can be just a recompilation and merging of different PDF files.

And you are on the right track that a program like Scribus should make the conversion.
The idea would be that you import the file inside a new document, with the same amount of pages, and export it with a better profile. I have not done that because I do not use Scribus.

But some sections on RGB could be the least of the file problems. For example, if the black text is in RGB, when converted it will become a nightmare. A photo can be converted directly from RGB to CMYK, but text needs to be converted to pure black.
The best option is to hire a Designer to take a close look at the file. Resolution, Color Swatches, Black on texts, and then RGB.
One problem could be not having the exact fonts used on the original file, so try to find the original file if possible, or let the designer to do the best conversion he can.

There is a trial period for Adobe Acrobat Pro. However you need to know what are you looking for, so I would not recommend doing it yourself.
